# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application i have created two components. Selector Component and Shifter Component. Selector components selects the list of items that needs to be updated. The selector component invokes a method in Shifter component that actually updates the item selected. The selector component calls a service which in turn invokes a url using http Get method to get the list of items to be updated. I am listing the items selected as hyperlinks. On clicking an item listed, a call to a method in shifter component is made.  This method calls a service which in turn invokes a http Patch method to update the item.

In this process I am getting an error

core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined

Here is my selector component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectorService } from '../selector.service';
import { Item, SelectorResponse } from '../selector-response';
import { ShifterRequest } from '../shifter-request';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CanonicalShifterRequest } from '../cshifter';
import { ShifterService } from '../shifter.service';
import { ShifterComponent } from '../shifter/shifter.component';

@component({
    selector: 'app-selector',
    template: 
        <div *ngIf="sdata">
        <h2>Items</h2>  
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let tci of getTags()">
                <a href="javascript:void90);" (click)="callupdate(tci.slector, tci.service)">{{tci.service}] - {{tci.selector}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
,
styles: []          
})

export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _selectorService: SelectorService){}
    public svs:ShifterComponent;
    public sdata: SelectorResponse;
    public cShifterRequest: CanaonicalShifterRequest[] =[];
    public services:string[] = ["myservice1",....
    public httpH:HttpHandler;
    public httpC:HttpClient = new HttpClient(this.httpH);

    ngOnInit(){
        this._selectorService.getEntries().subscribe(data => this.sdata = data);
    }

    getTags(){
        //my method to get the items 
    }
    callUpdate(instanceSel:String, servicename: String){
        var shifterComponent:ShifterComponent(new ShifterService(this.httpc));
        if (shifterComponent instanceof ShifterComponent)
            shifterComponent.updateServiceCaller(instanceSel, servicename);
    }
}
```

Here is my shifter component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectorService } from '../selector.service';
import { Item, SelectorResponse } from '../selector-response';
import { ShifterRequest } from '../shifter-request';
import { HttpClient  } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CanonicalShifterRequest } from '../cshifter';
import { ShifterService } from '../shifter.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-shifter',
    template: <h2>update</h2>,
    styles: []
})

export class ShifterComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _shifterService: ShifterService ) {}

    public instanceSel:String:
    public servicename:String;

    public udata: any;

    updateServiceCaller(instanceSel:String, servicename:String){
        if(this._shifterService instanceof ShifterService)
            this._shifterService.updateService(instanceSel, servicename).subscribe(data => this.udata = data);
}
}
```

Here is my shifter service

```
pimport { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ShifterRequest } from './shifter-request';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShifterService{

private servicename:String;
private _url:String = "";
shifterRequest: 

headerDict = {... } //my headers

headers = new HttpHeaders(this.headerDict)

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

updateService(instanceSel: String, servicename: String) : Observable<any> {

this._url="https://xyz/" + servicename;

if(this.http instanceof HttpClient){
    return this.http.patch<any>(this._url, {..my request goes here.}, {headers: this.headers});
}
else{
    console.log("shifter service nul http");
    return null;
}
}
}
```

i think the issue is due to the fact that i am not sure how to initialize the HttpClient in the SelectorComponent.

Can someone help to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to initialize the HttpClient just request it in the constructor, like you already do in SelectorComponent for SelectorService

```
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _selectorService: SelectorService,
         private httpC: HttpClient){}
```

Angular will read these "params" and provide all the required services for you through Dependency Injection. After this is done if you find and error something like `Cannot find provider for HttpClient` just add `HttpClientModule` to your AppModule imports